# im trying to access command promt in an docker contain from my windows machine it was hung in that state "docker run -it 9da089657551 sh",

Tags: docker

I'm trying to access command promt in an docker container from my windows 10 machine it was hung black state . Command > "docker run -it 9da089657551 sh", anyone has any idea how to execute sh in an container?

Comment: Wrong site to ask the question, but if you want a prompt in a running container you use `exec`, not `run`.

Comment: i have tried exec too still same response.

Answer (score 1):

What is the current entrypoint of the container? You might need to add that to the docker run command: `docker run -it <image name> --entrypoint sh`